# How to Enable Administration section & Left side menu on New UI 9.6

Tags: content-manager, sites-9.6, experience-space

We are upgrading Tridion from 9.1 to 9.6. We are enabled New UI (Experience Space) for Tridion Sites 9.6.

we are unable to see Administration Section and Left side Menu on New UI. Can you please suggest how to enable these sections.?

Comment: I added Experience Space to the question and as a tag to help others follow Q&A on the "new UI." :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not all functionality has yet been exposed in the New UI.  For some functionality you will need to switch back to the older Content Manager Explorer.